# Android YouTube API: Can't reinitialize YouTubePlayerFragment with new YouTube video

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to load a different video into a YoutubePlayer fragment when a button is clicked.  My button has an onclick listener of testClick.  When I click the button, I get the following exception: "UsupportedExeception: no views can be added on top of player".  The initialize method also isn't being called when I initialize the new video from my onclick method.  How can I a new YouTubeVideo to be loaded into the previously used YouTubePlayerFragment, and how I can get the initialize method to be called from my onClick method?

```
public class ExersizeListActivity extends Activity implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exersize_list);
}

public void testClick(View v) {
    //new YouTube Fragment to replace old one
    YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment=YouTubePlayerFragment.newInstance();
    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(YoutubeAPIKey.API_KEY, this);

    FragmentManager fragManager=getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragManager.beginTransaction();


    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();       
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
        YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
    Log.e(null, "it bombed");

}

//not being called, and in current state would reinitialize with the same video
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0,
        YouTubePlayer youtubePlayer, boolean arg2) {
    youtubePlayer.cueVideo("YNKehLXpLRI");      
}

}

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/randomizeButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Randomize!" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/youtube_fragment"
    android:onClick="testClick"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than defining the fragment in the xml layout file with the `<fragment>` tag, define a FrameLayout container, necessary when changing fragments dinamically at [runtime](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#AddAtRuntime):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/randomizeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Randomize!" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:onClick="testClick"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You will need to add the first `YouTubeVideoFragment` in `onCreate()` with a `FragmentTransaction`, and when the user clicks the button, the code you already have in `testClick()` should work.